# What's CRC with 64b in and 32b out?

Tags: boost, fpga, crc

I'm developing a software utility to transfer some data to a pci-e board. To avoid the data transfer fault, I've add a CRC field in every packet, so that the pci-e board can verify the received data with the CRC value.

Then we found out that the CRC value failed to pass the verification.

I'm using the **boost::crc_32_type** to generate the CRC value while the hardware guy told me that the CRC implementation in the board is from http://www.easics.com/webtools/crctool and they're using the **64** data bus width version of **CRC32** - ETHERNET / AAL5.

So, is it possible to use boost::crc_32_type to work with the one they're using?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

[**edit 2013.02.20**]

1. the working crc template shall have the following definition:

   boost::crc_optimal<32, 0x04C11DB7, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x0, false, false>
2. the order of every 8 bytes shall be reversed before being processed
3. std::for_each is used instead of process_bytes to get the result, I still don't quite understand the difference between them though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `crc_32_type` - first you have to make sure your bytes are going in the same order as the bytes the hardware guys are.  The convention used by the EASICS code is that the first byte in the stream goes into Data[63:56].

Comment: Based on your advice, I've reversed the byte order for every 8-bytes unit in the message, but the result is still not different with one in hardware. So, the code from EASICS is still CRC32 while optimized for 64bit data input?

Comment: How have you got your polynomial value?  That can get bit-reversed or byte reversed also, depending

Comment: Thanks for your reply again:) The polinomial we've used on EASICS are (0 1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11 12 16 22 23 26 32), the one I'm using in crc_32_type is the default 0x04C11DB7. If I understand it correctly, they are the same thing (from IEEE 802.3)?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that there is a comment in the EASICS generated file: // convention: the first serial bit is D[63].
Does that mean I should reverse the whole bit order for every 8-bytes unit?